# Django Admin refining selectbox values based on another selectbox

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have models for the following:

Country
Prov/State
City
Region
Community

Is there a way in the Django admin to filter the values in the select boxes based on the selection in the previous select box?
eg: I select Canada in the country select box, then in the Prov/State select box I am only presented with the Provinces. Once that is selected, the City select box only presents cities within the Province selected. etc...

I have been looking at the formfield_for_foreignkey, but I haven't been able to get it working just yet. I may not be understanding the use correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, it appears that I will have to dig into something based on the Ajax framework to do what I want to do. For those interested, the following are links to some sites that I found to be somewhat useful.
[DajaxProject](http://www.dajaxproject.com/)
[Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/)

If anyone has any other suggestions, please let me know.